# echo php code by php; is that possible

Tags: php

I want to echo out the php code itself for educational purposes. Is this possible? At the same time I also need the code as php code to be executed.

adding html `special-chars` to this:

```
$this->art = file_get_contents("$this->Mainpage/$this->dir/$this->article");
```

it becomes:

```
$this->Art = htmlspecialchars( file_get_contents("$this->Mainpage/$this->dir/$this->Artikel"));
```

But this still does not output the code itself as the php interpreter seems to get hold of the code and directly interprets it. `htmlspecialchars ()` has only got an effect on the html code, you then get to see the article in brackets.

I also tried using `.html` files instead of `.php` files. But PHP interprets it even if you rename it to `.jpeg`.

I'm at my wit's end. I would be grateful for any answer. Thanking in advance.

Comment: `file_get_contents` doesn't interpret any PHP, there's something else going on here. What's actually in the file in question?

Comment: How do you actually echo the code?

Comment: simply do this `str_replace('<?php','',$yourdata);`

Comment: $this->Art = file_get_contents("$this->Mainpage/$this->dir/$this->Artikel");
     $this->section = explode ("***End_Embed***", $this->Art);
     $this->Meta_Text=$this->section[0];
     $this->content=$this->section[1];echo ("$this->content");

Comment: but I'll try Feroz's code. Thank you. Just trying to grasp  what is going on inside the skin of php as it were.

Comment: Don't you know this kind of stuff is [dangerous](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=OqxLmLUT-qc)?

Answer (score 3):

I dont understand, why one would actually consider doing it this way, but it is pretty easy. 
file_get_content will not run the code, while include will.

```
define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

// Logic starts here
public function main() {
    echo '<hr><pre>' . $this->educlude($this->Mainpage . DS. $this->dir . DS . $this->Artikle) . '</pre>';
}

public function educlude($file) {
    include $file;
    return htmlspecialchars(file_get_contents($file));
}
```

This will echo

> Hello World
>
> ---
>
> ```
> <?php echo 'Hello World';
> ```

for given file:

`<?php echo 'Hello World';`

Answer (score 0):

'echo' seems to somehow process php-code, even if it is a txt file. So before echoing I did this, the precondition being that the code is saved as .txt:

```
$this->Art =nl2br (htmlspecialchars(file_get_contents("$this->Mainpage/$this->dir/$this->Artikel")));
```

if you do this with a file ending with .php the code seems to be even processed by 'file_get_contents' So you have to use .txt.

Comment: It does not. You are probably downloading a file (file_get_contents works for local and remote files), so your webserver preprocesses the php code.